# Infix to Postfix conversion with stacks and queues. Trying to convert (A+B into AB+). Not worrying about parentheses right now

Tags: java, stack, queue

The program I have now works for stuff like A+B for all operators. It also works for examples like A+BxC however if you input AxB+C it comes out wrong. I'm just not seeing where I'm going wrong. (I know that "x" isn't the multiplication operator for Java but the asterisk wouldn't show up). Also, we're using a Stack and Queue class that we created.

Why won't A/B+C work?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class PostfixEval {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("infile.txt"); // infile contains single expression
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(file);
    Queue Q1 = new Queue();
    Queue Q2 = new Queue();
    Stack S1 = new Stack();

    while (kb.hasNext()) {
        String equation = kb.next();
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < equation.length(); i++) {
            ch = equation.charAt(i);
            Q1.add2Rear(ch);
        }

        while (!Q1.ismtQ()) {
            ch = Q1.removeFront();
            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                Q2.add2Rear(ch);
            } else if (isOperator(ch)) {
                if (!S1.ismt() && checkPrecedence(ch) <= checkPrecedence(S1.top())) {
                    Q2.add2Rear(S1.pop());
                    ;
                }
                S1.push(ch);
            }

        }
        while (!S1.ismt()) {
            Q2.add2Rear(S1.pop());
        }
    }

    while (!Q2.ismtQ()) {
        System.out.print(Q2.removeFront());
    }

    kb.close();
}

public static boolean isOperator(char ch) {
    boolean retval = false;
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '/' || ch == '*')
        retval = true;
    return retval;
}

public static int checkPrecedence(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
        return 1;

    case '*':
    case '/':
        return 2;
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Static Class

```
public class Stack implements StackInterface {

ArrayList<Character> stack = new ArrayList<Character>();

public void push(char ch) {
    stack.add(ch);
}

public char top() {
    char myCh;
    myCh = stack.get(stack.size() - 1);
    return myCh;
}

public char pop() {
    char myCh;
    myCh = stack.get(stack.size() - 1);
    stack.remove(stack.get(stack.size() - 1));
    return myCh;
}

public boolean ismt() {
    boolean retval = true;
    retval = stack.isEmpty();
    return retval;
}

}
```

Queue Class

```
public class Queue implements QueueInterface {

ArrayList<Character> que = new ArrayList<Character>();

@Override
public void add2Rear(char ch) { // add element to rear of queue
    que.add(ch);

}

@Override
public char removeFront() { // returns first element AND removes it
    char retval = '1';
    retval = que.remove(0);
    return retval;
}

@Override
public char front() { // returns first element
    char retval = '1';
    retval = que.get(0);
    return retval;
}

@Override
public boolean ismtQ() { // true: if empty, false: if otherwise
    boolean retval = true;
    retval = que.isEmpty();
    return retval;
}

}
```

Comment: It's no good building these things 'not worrying about parentheses right now'. You'll only end up with something you may have to change extensively. It's a standard algorithm, just implement it all.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm new here and not sure if I should answer my own question but I figured it out (in terms of the assignment that I was tasked to complete) and maybe someone else needs the answer.

This is the updated code:

```
if (!S1.ismt()) {
                    if(checkPrecedence(ch) <= checkPrecedence(S1.top())){ 
                        Q2.add2Rear(S1.pop());
                    }
                }
```

If anyone has any better options, feel free to post!

Comment: This is no different in effect from what you posted in your question. You must have changed something else.